# Is the license for Dance Monkey free?

Tags: youtube

I don't think so.
However, there are so many cover songs on YouTube.
So, are these copyright violations?
Or is Dance Monkey free, am I wrong?

Comment: You need to know that YouTube often doesn't remove videos with copyright infringements anymore. Nowadays, the ad revenue gets redirected towards the original content rights holders and the video can stay up, unless the rights holders don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your country, the website you're uploading to and your usage of both audio and video, the copyright-laws make it legal or illegal to use a specific song.

If you create a video-essay about music-production and must use the song as an example to show your point, you will, in many cases and places not break any laws. If you combine a still-image with the song and upload this in its entirety than you will break the law in almost every case and place.

Copyright to music is no black-and-white topic, and if you're considering using music from an artist, I would seriously recommend reading up on the laws that are applicable where you live, so to not risk a hefty fine.

Youtube has a special approach to this case, in which - when a video uses copyrighted music - the video's revenue (money from ads) will go directly to the artist. If, however, the music is not registered at a database (in germany it's the GEMA, to name an example), the video can be blocked everywhere and you will get a strike. 3 Strikes mean that your channel will be terminated.
So you will likely not risk getting sued when using music in a youtube-video, but I would recommend reading up on the laws or asking a lawyer nonetheless. Copyright should be taken very seriously.